# Problema con envió de datos en react js

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, upload

Ahora mismo me encuentro realizando una aplicación donde debo enviar datos de un formulario a la base de datos, en este formulario se envían también unos campos con imágenes y lo que hago es enviarlas al servidor agregarle un nombre y ese nombre lo retorno al cliente para guardar el nombre de la imagen junto con los demás datos el inconveniente que tengo es que el guarda los datos y las imágenes correctamente pero no guarda los nombres de las imágenes, aquí mi código:

Funciones de envio de datos y imagenes

```
const submitFinanciado = async (e) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();      

      const tabla = "datos";
      let res = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:${portServer}/createGeneral/${tabla}`,
        {
          nombre: nombre,
          apellido: apellido,                  
          image1: images[0],
          image2: images[1],          
        }
      );
      Swal.fire(res.data.err ? res.data.err : res.data.msg);
      upload();
      navigate("/home");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

const upload = async () => {
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("image1", image1);
    formdata.append("image2", image2);    

    try {
      let campana = "tyt";
      let metodo = "financiado";
      let res = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:${portServer}/images/${campana}/${metodo}`,
        formdata
      );
      let { rows } = res.data;
      images.push(rows[0]);
      images.push(rows[1]);      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Formulario

```
<form onSubmit={submitFinanciado} className="p-4 rounded-md shadow-xl">       
        <div className="divider" />
        <div className="grid grid-cols-8 gap-6">          
         <div className="col-span-1 flex justify-evenly">
          <label className="label text-sm">Nombre</label>
          <input
           type="text"
           className="input input-bordered w-full"
           value={nombre}
           onChange={(e) => setNombre(e.target.value)}
           required
          />
          </div>       
          <div className="col-span-2 col-start-1">
            <label className="label text-sm">
              Apellido
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="input input-bordered w-full"
              value={apellido}
              onChange={(e) => setApellido(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-span-2 col-start-1">
            <label className="label text-sm">
              Imagen1
            </label>
            <input
              type="file"
              className="input input-bordered w-full"
              value={image1}
              onChange={(e) => setImage1(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-span-2 col-start-1">
            <label className="label text-sm">
              Imagen2
            </label>
            <input
              type="file"
              className="input input-bordered w-full"
              value={image2}
              onChange={(e) => setImage2(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
       </div>
 </form>
```

y aquí una imagen de como me envía los datos a la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

creo que solo subes las imágenes y no su descripción al enviarlo a la db

```
const objeto = {
    imagen1:{
        descripcion: "imagen1",
        imagen:images[0]
    },
    imagen2:{
        descripcion: "imagen2",
        imagen:images[1]   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Está fue la solución que encontré para mi problema, espero que si alguien se topa con lo mismo le pueda ser de ayuda.

```
const submitFinanciado = async (e) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault(); 

      await upload();    

      const tabla = "datos";
      let res = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:${portServer}/createGeneral/${tabla}`,
        {
          nombre: nombre,
          apellido: apellido,                  
          image1: images[0],
          image2: images[1],          
        }
      );
      Swal.fire(res.data.err ? res.data.err : res.data.msg);      
      navigate("/home");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```